# 3RSSH smoothing in Python

Tags: python, excel, numpy, scipy, smoothing

I'm looking for running median smoothing implementations for Python. 3RSSH in particular.

There is an implementation for Excel that works fine:
http://www.quantdec.com/Excel/smoothing.htm

Also, R's smooth function has 3RSSH: http://exploratorydataanalysis.blogspot.com/2009/03/smoothing-on-r.html

But I want a Python version, preferably working with numpy/scipy and can't find one.
So far, I've had no luck with googling.

Are there any libraries implementing such smoothing functions? Or am I destined to write one? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think I saw a 3RSSH implementation, but you could try using [`scipy.signal`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html) to try and make one.

Maybe these will be enough for your application?

[`scipy.signal.medfilt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.medfilt.html#scipy.signal.medfilt)

[`scipy.signal.medfilt2d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.medfilt2d.html#scipy.signal.medfilt2d)

[`scipy.ndimage.filters.median_filter`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.median_filter.html)